# How to return multiple data when use loop in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to filter data when user check multiple checkbox and show data from this View (1) to another View (2)

I tried using Model and make loop in Controller (2) to get value checbox when user check multiple checbox,

I have a problem with loop in controller when return... I can't return multiple data when user check multiple checkbox.

It only returns the data of the last loop

Controller

```
ContainerTrackingSystemEntities db = new ContainerTrackingSystemEntities();
    BaseModel modelResult = new BaseModel();
    BaseModel model = new BaseModel();
    // GET: CurrentContainerReport
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //if (Session["User"] == null)
        //{
        //    SetAlert("Vui lòng đăng nhập", "info");
        //    return RedirectToAction("LoginUsers", "Users");
        //}
        ViewBag.PortCode = db.APS_Inventory_Port.OrderBy(n => n.Code);


        //model.aPS_Inventory_Containers = (from c in db.APS_Inventory_Container select c).GroupBy(n => n.Size).Select(n => n.FirstOrDefault()).Distinct().ToList();
        model.aPS_Inventory_OwnerAgentss = (from o in db.APS_Inventory_OwnerAgent select o).OrderBy(n => n.Code).ToList();
        model.aPS_Inventory_Portss = (from p in db.APS_Inventory_Port select p).OrderBy(n => n.Code).ToList();
        model.aPS_Inventory_Containerss = (from c in db.APS_Inventory_Container select c).GroupBy(n => n.Size).Select(n => n.FirstOrDefault()).OrderBy(n => n.Size).ToList();




        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(BaseModel model)
    {

        TempData["model"] = model;

        return RedirectToAction("Search");
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Search(BaseModel model)
    {
         model = (BaseModel) TempData["model"];

        List<APS_Inventory_Container> aPS_Inventory_Containers = new List<APS_Inventory_Container>();

        for (int i = 0; i < model.aPS_Inventory_OwnerAgentss.Where(n => n.IsCheckedOwnerAgent == true).Count(); i++)
        {
            bool isChecked = model.aPS_Inventory_OwnerAgentss[i].IsCheckedOwnerAgent;
            Guid? OwnerID = model.aPS_Inventory_OwnerAgentss[i].OwnerAgentID;

            aPS_Inventory_Containers = (from c in db.APS_Inventory_Container
                    where c.PortCode == model.aps_inventory_port.Code && c.OwnerAgentID == OwnerID
                    select c).ToList();


        }    
        return View(aPS_Inventory_Containers);
    }
```

View Index

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.aPS_Inventory_OwnerAgentss.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(item => item.aPS_Inventory_OwnerAgentss[i].Code)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(item => item.aPS_Inventory_OwnerAgentss[i].IsCheckedOwnerAgent, new { @checked = "checked" })
                                @Html.HiddenFor(item => item.aPS_Inventory_OwnerAgentss[i].OwnerAgentID)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(item => item.aPS_Inventory_OwnerAgentss[i].Code)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
```

View Search

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(itemSelect => item.Code)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(itemSelect => item.Status)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(itemSelect => item.PortCode)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(itemSelect => item.Size)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(itemSelect => item.Type)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(itemSelect => item.DateofManufactured)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(itemSelect => item.OwnerAgentID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(itemSelect => item.Comments)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(itemSelect => item.approve)
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
```

And Base Model

```
public class BaseModel
{
    public APS_Inventory_Bill aps_inventory_bill { get; set; }
    public APS_Inventory_BillDetails aps_inventory_billdetails { get; set; }
    public APS_Inventory_Container aps_inventory_container { get; set; }
    public APS_Inventory_Depot aps_inventory_depot { get; set; }
    public APS_Inventory_Port aps_inventory_port { get; set; }
    public APS_Inventory_OwnerAgent aps_inventory_owneragent { get; set; }


    public List<APS_Inventory_Container> aPS_Inventory_Containerss { get; set; }
    public List<APS_Inventory_OwnerAgent> aPS_Inventory_OwnerAgentss { get; set; }
    public List<APS_Inventory_Port> aPS_Inventory_Portss { get; set; }
    public List<APS_Inventory_Bill> aPS_Inventory_Billss { get; set; }
    public List<APS_Inventory_BillDetails> aPS_Inventory_BillDetailss { get; set; }



}
```

And if anyone has another way please let me know 
Thanks !

Comment: Please add your code to the question *as text*. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the line `aPS_Inventory_Containers = ....` you **overwrite** the value of `aPS_Inventory_Containers` every time you run the loop. In other words, you replace its previous value with a new value. So after the loop finishes, there's only the last value remaining - you have destroyed all the others. You probably want to *add* items to the list, instead of replacing the whole list each time.

Try this instead:

```
aPS_Inventory_Containers.AddRange( 
  (from c in db.APS_Inventory_Container
   where c.PortCode == model.aps_inventory_port.Code && c.OwnerAgentID == OwnerID
   select c).ToList()
);
```

Comment: Now, It's only return the data of first checkbox !

Comment: I don't really see how that could be possible, unless you simply don't have any values associated with the other Owner IDs in your database, or you forgot to check the other boxes when you tested. Are you sure that's what's happening? Have you stepped through the code with the debugger to verify the behaviour?

Comment: it only return the data of first checkbox although I don't select that checkbox...

Comment: like I said, have you stepped through with the debugger? What items are marked as checked inside `model.aPS_Inventory_OwnerAgentss`? How many times does the `for` loop run? What is the contents of `aPS_Inventory_Containers` after each run of the loop?

Comment: I solved the problem, I just need to edit the for loop and add condition isChecked to check it... thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Was `.Where(n => n.IsCheckedOwnerAgent == true)` not already doing that job?

Comment: Ok. Not sure I understand what else you needed to change then, but anyway - if my answer helped you solve the problem, please remember to mark it as "accepted" (click the tick mark next to the answer so it turns green). thanks and good luck :-)